# EntityManager refresh

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I have web application using JPA. This entity manager keeps bunch of entites and suddenly I update the database from other side. I use **MySQL** and I use **PhpMyAdmin** and change some row.

How to tell entity manager to re-synchronize, e.g. to forgot all the entites in cache?

I know there is `refresh(Object)` method, but is there any possibility how to do `refreshAll()` or something what results in this?

It is sure this is expensive operation but if it has to be done.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll()
```

`Refresh` is something different since it **modifies your object**. This line will just `empty the cache`, so if you fetch objects changed outside the entity manager, it will do an actual database query instead of using the outdated `cached` value.

Comment: I know this is a couple years old, but I wanted to throw my two cents in. I'm not exactly sure this can be called the answer. evictAll() works in the scenario where you want the new data being persisted/merged to ignore what's cached and force update/insert the database. However, evictAll() does NOT work (at least for me) in the scenario where first the backend database changes a value and THEN you expect the change to show up when pulled from the datastore. In my experience, the cache still overrides what was changed in the backend.

Comment: @JasonWasho, do you have a solution to cache still overriding issue?

Comment: entityManager.clear() empties the persistence context. This causes the entity to be fetched again from database.

Comment: entityManager.clear() is the only thing, that worked for us. Unfortunately, it fires a query on each single entity.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue and the `evictAll()` line above worked for me.

Alternatively, the `@Cache` annotation on the entity class worked too, with the benefit of being able to control caching parameters:

```
@Cache(coordinationType=CacheCoordinationType.INVALIDATE_CHANGED_OBJECTS)
```

See: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching

Answer (score 4):

If you are using EclipseLink instead of Hibernate the hint is:

```
em.createNamedQuery("SomeEntity.SomeNamedQuery")
.setHint(QueryHints.REFRESH, true)
.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, for some people (like me) that tried to add *factory.getCache().evictAll();* and doesn't work, and are used JPA + Hibernate, to refresh a query add the hint *org.hibernate.cacheMode* to *IGNORE*. Example:

```
em.createNamedQuery("SomeEntity.SomeNamedQuery")
  .setHint("org.hibernate.cacheMode", "IGNORE")
  .getResultList();
```

Answer (score 2):

cache.evictAll is not working for me. So to retrieve data pushed from another app, I peform :

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

After that, my find query retrieves refreshed data. I don't know if it's very safe solution but it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

When you read an object into an EntityManager, it becomes part of the persistence context, and the same object will remain in the EntityManager until you either clear() it and get a new EntityManager. 
So if you update the database, the EntityManager will not see the change unless you call refresh() on the object, or clear() the EntityManager. This has nothing to do with the shared cache (L2) or the persistence context (L1).      If you also also using a shared cache, and updating the database directly, then your shared cache will be out of date. You need to refresh() the object, or mark it as invalid to be refreshed the next time it is queried.

Code must follow the way like.
DETACH
REFRESH
MERGE 
FLUSH

Comment: But if you try to refresh a detached entity, you will get a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity not managed". So you have to detach, merge, refresh instead?