# JPA Cache: how do you get updated results from a db view after a table in view is updated

Tags: jpa, caching, model-view-controller, view, mariadb

In the db (mariadb) I have a view defined as a select of data coming from the join of several tables:

```
    CREATE VIEW `obiettivideco` AS 
    SELECT 
      `codici`.`id` AS  `idc`,
      `codici`.`codice` AS `codice`,
      `codici`.`sub` AS `sub`,
      `codici`.`descrizione` AS `descrizionec`,
      `eo`.`id` AS `ide`,
      `eo`.`Descrizione` AS `descrizionee`,
      `obiettivi`.`id` AS `ido`,
      `obiettivi`.`inizio` AS `inizio`,
      `obiettivi`.`fine` AS `fine`,
      `obiettivi`.`valore` AS `valore` 
    FROM (
      (`obiettivi` JOIN `eo` 
      ON((`obiettivi`.`eo` = `eo`.`id`))) JOIN `codici` 
      ON((`obiettivi`.`codice` = `codici`.`id`))
);
```

Above that layer I generated entities from tables (and from the view as well) in order to have the Model of the MVC pattern. 
Then in the Controller made with some managed beans I wrote some logic that enables the view (JSF) to show a selection of the above view.
When data has to be modified changes are persisted with the help of the tables entities (e.g.

```
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(obiettivo);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
```

where obiettivo is an object of Class Obiettivi which, in turn, is the entity modelling the obiettivi table.
The problem arises if I try to display an update of the obiettivideco selection: jpa cache seems to not be aware that changes in obiettivo will make obiettivideco out of date as well.

I spent a couple of days before I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43093854/7853053) related to the entitymanager refresh that solved my problem:

```
    q.setHint(QueryHints.REFRESH, true);
    obiettivideco = (List<Obiettivideco>) q.getResultList();
```

Becouse of my low reputation I could not upvote that answer so I'm posting this already answered question in the hope that would save someone else headhaches.